# facing issue while using tricycle_controller in ros2 humble

Tags: ros2

https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/tree/master/tricycle_controller

```
ros2 launch  articubot_one launch_sim.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/amol/.ros/log/2024-01-11-22-15-09-978754-amol-pc-51469
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [51471]
[INFO] [joy_node-2]: process started with pid [51473]
[INFO] [teleop_node-3]: process started with pid [51475]
[INFO] [twist_mux-4]: process started with pid [51477]
[INFO] [gzserver-5]: process started with pid [51479]
[INFO] [gzclient-6]: process started with pid [51481]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-7]: process started with pid [51483]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [51517]
[INFO] [spawner-9]: process started with pid [51524]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1704991510.539295126] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment LH_Free_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1704991510.539390449] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RH_Free_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1704991510.539399567] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1704991510.539404579] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1704991510.539409356] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment laser_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1704991510.539414139] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment steering_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1704991510.539419057] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment traction_wheel
[teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1704991510.565056993] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Teleop enable button 6.
[teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1704991510.565853235] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo on button 7.
[teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1704991510.566464710] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Linear axis x on 1 at scale 0.500000.
[teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1704991510.566887056] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo for linear axis x is scale 1.000000.
[teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1704991510.567365879] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Angular axis yaw on 0 at scale 0.500000.
[teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1704991510.567954660] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo for angular axis yaw is scale 1.000000.
[twist_mux-4] [INFO] [1704991510.572422076] [twist_mux]: Topic handler 'topics.joystick' subscribed to topic 'cmd_vel_joy': timeout = 0.500000s , priority = 100.
[twist_mux-4] [INFO] [1704991510.574910450] [twist_mux]: Topic handler 'topics.navigation' subscribed to topic 'cmd_vel': timeout = 0.500000s , priority = 10.
[twist_mux-4] [INFO] [1704991510.575257542] [twist_mux]: Topic handler 'topics.tracker' subscribed to topic 'cmd_vel_tracker': timeout = 0.500000s , priority = 20.
[spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1704991511.156391724] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1704991511.156689624] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-7] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-7]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1704991511.158477863] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1704991511.169227154] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1704991511.169488303] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1704991512.924717393] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1704991513.156890162] [spawner_tri_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1704991513.162500009] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[gzserver-5] [WARN] [1704991513.270410187] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=scan'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=scan' instead.
[gzserver-5] [WARN] [1704991513.274465144] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=scan'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=scan' instead.
[spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1704991513.278257286] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [my_bot]
[gzserver-5] [INFO] [1704991513.299429049] [tricycle_controller]: Subscribe to [/cmd_vel]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 51483]
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1704991515.164652001] [spawner_tri_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1704991515.169179368] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1704991517.171187670] [spawner_tri_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1704991517.176182756] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1704991519.179196699] [spawner_tri_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-9] [INFO] [1704991519.182697099] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [ERROR] [1704991521.185940978] [spawner_tri_cont]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-9] [ERROR] [1704991521.189209220] [spawner_joint_broad]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-8]: process has died [pid 51517, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner tri_cont --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-9]: process has died [pid 51524, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_broad --ros-args'].
```

Comment: colcon test result gives zero errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced similar problems using controller manager, check the config files, see if all the controller names are defined properly and are written the same in your launch file.